# Using wish for present or future tenses

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, wish

Is the sentence below correct:

> I wish he goes to where he loves.

Please supply reasons for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that I would call it *wrong*, but it's not idiomatic, at the very least.  It's a little hard to say if it's "correct" or not because you don't tell us what you want the sentence to mean.

---

[With the verb *wish*, we normally use either the modal **could** or **would** if we're talking about the future](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/wishes-and-hypotheses):

> I wish **he would go**...

or the past tense if we're talking about a wish for the present or in general:

> I wish **he went**...

but never the present tense "I wish he goes".  (Yes, I know this seems very illogical.)

If you use the verb **hope** instead, you don't have to use a modal: I **hope he goes**...

---

**To where he loves** is, again, not exactly wrong but kind of stilted and non-idiomatic.  "Where he loves" sounds like it means "the place where he performs the action of loving" - consider "where he sleeps" or "where he eats."

If you mean you hope that he goes to **a place that he loves**, it would sound more fluent to say that.  Alternately, it's idiomatic to say *where he likes* to mean "wherever he feels like going".

---

Overall, I would probably phrase the sentence as

> I wish he would go to the place that he loves.

Comment: It's a wish about future. And yes, I agree about the normal used form. I meant "the place that" by "where".